# Google Apps Script on spreadsheet to edit multiple match row

Tags: google-apps-script

This function works fine except that it's very slow.  I wonder if there's any other method that would work better and faster.  For example, using QUERY to modify the match criteria or something. 
Note: the worksheet is sorted with the 1st column in group so these target items could be anywhere down.

```
function changeownership(account, volume, newowner, changetime) {
    var values = [ [ newowner, account, changetime ] ];
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    for (var n = 1 ; n < ss.getSheets()[0].getLastRow(); n++) {
        var owner = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(n, 1).getValue();
        if (owner == account) {
            volume = volume - 1;
            var range = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("A"+n+":C"+n);
            range.setValues(values);
        }
        if (volume < 1)
            break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading and writing to cells one at a time, read and write large blocks of data at once. Use `Sheet.getDataRange()` to get a range covering all the data in the sheet, and `Range.getValues()` to get a 2D array of values in that range. See the Apps Script [Best Practices guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices#batchOperations) for more information.